# Python psycopg2 SELECT return None

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I try to use psycog2 into my python script.

I have a `get_db()` function into `db.py` file (I need the choice between sqlite and psql) :

```
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        info_db = getDatabaseType()
        if info_db['type'] != 'pgsql': # If wrong type is setup, use sqlite by default
            g.db = sqlite3.connect(
                current_app.config['DATABASE'],
                detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
            )
            g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        else:
            conn = psycopg2.connect(
                "dbname=" + info_db['db'] +
                " user=" + info_db['user'] +
                " password=" + info_db['pwd'])
            conn.autocommit = True
            g.db = conn.cursor()
    return g.db
```

And here is the code to makes a select in `auth.py` file (same level as `db.py`):

```
def load_logged_in_user():
    user_id = session.get('user_id')

    if user_id is None:
        g.user = None
    else:
        db = get_db()
        tes = db.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
        users = tes.fetchall()
```

I have the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

If I do the same command in the `db.py` file, it's working.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: g.db contains the cursor, as expected. when I print `db` in the second file, I also have the cursor..

Comment: You may also want to tag this with ```flask```. It would help explain ```g```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
tes = db.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
users = tes.fetchall()
```

`db.execute` returns None to be assigned to `tes`.

You need to do:

```
db.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
users = db.fetchall()
```

The cursor executes the command and then you fetch from the cursor.